# How to correctly initialize $GLOBALS['TSFE']

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions

In my TYPO3 extension, I made a custom controller class that is called from some hook in the TYPO3 backend.

In this controller I would like to get some stuff from `$GLOBALS['TSFE']` but when I do `var_dump($GLOBALS['TSFE'])` I receive `null`. The question is how can I correctly initialize `$GLOBALS['TSFE'`]?

Comment: Why do you need $GLOBALS['TSFE'] in the Backend? Please add some context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try something like this:

```
$GLOBALS['TSFE'] = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Controller\TypoScriptFrontendController',$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS'], $id, $type);
```

Comment: Anyone know how to do that in TYPO3 10?

Comment: @mcyg For TYPO3 10 see https://stackoverflow.com/a/68020537/415353

Comment: Please add some more context if and when this is recommended and for which TYPO3 versions. Usually TSFE is inititalized in the FE and not in the BE. If you do need it regardless, there are sometimes better ways to achieve things.

Comment: @SybillePeters thanks for your interest, but It was 5 years ago, so I have no context anymore.

Answer (score 3):

While $GLOBALS['TSFE'] is the instantiation of TypoScriptFrontendController and you can correctly instantiate it with makeInstance as described, why would you want to do that?

As you said, you are working in the *Backend*, TypoScriptFrontendController gives you various information about the currently rendered page (in the *Frontend*).

So, while you **can** instantiate the TSTypoScriptFrontendControllerFE, there is usually no need to: TYPO3 instantiates it in the Frontend.

Before instantiating it, I would first check: What's the usecase? And maybe there is some better way to do what you want to do.